# Pages Input per Second Spiking Daily

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, data-pages, metrics

I'm still learning a lot about SQL Server and pretty green, but doing the best I can as an accidental DBA.

We have recently purchased a SQL monitoring software package, and after adjusting the threshold on alerting so I'm not bombarded with false positive warnings, I noticed that the pages input per second spikes every day at exactly the same time:  6:20:30 PM.  The only variation in time over the last week was just last night, when it alerted again at 6:19:39 PM.... very very close to the same time!

I have checked the server job schedules and it appears there are no jobs scheduled around that time.  The earliest job we have kicking off is at 9pm daily, so that's not it.

Can anyone tell me what I can look at (or for) that will help me find what is causing this to happen at exactly the same time every day?

Thanks much!

Comment: Have you tried contacting the vendor you purchased your monitoring tool from for guidance? I don't think I've ever seen a "pages input per second" metric. Can you share a screenshot of what you're looking at?

Comment: Sure thing @sp_BlitzErik

Here is an image of the occurrences of the metric: 
https://imageshack.com/a/img924/6827/mIryHd.png

And another one showing the detail when I click on one of the incidents: 
https://imageshack.com/a/img923/4348/c4lG2a.png

Answer (score 1):

It is OS performance counter and refers to reads of page file. Generally it points to low memory condition on server. With your provided info no specification can be made about the issue. You need to monitor the server processes at that time. Also have a look at other applications consumption if exist on same server along with SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  When you say to "monitor the server processes at that time", can you please elaborate on this?  I'm not sure what process or types of processes I should be looking for, or how to monitor them since our office closes at 4:30pm and this doesn't happen until 6:20pm.  Just not quite sure what I'm looking for or where to look for it.  Thanks much.

Comment: You would have to schedule a job that can capture and save the results of sp_who2 or preferable sp_whoisactive (it is not a system SP. Can be downloaded and created on server). Else u can configure a trace to capture the activity. Make sure to follow the best practices for traces to avoid load on server.